# Ejercicio de listas dentro de funciones en python

Tags: python

```
def hay_Alguno(l,e):
    for i in range (0,len(l),1):
        if l[i] ==e:
            return True
        return False
l=[0,0,0,1]
e=8
l1=hay_Alguno(l,e)
print(l1) 

def comprar_figus(figus_total):
    return random.randint(1,figus_total)
figus=comprar_figus(15)
print(figus)

def cuantas_figus(figus_total):
    album = [0]
    album = album*figus_total
    i=0
    while hay_Alguno(album,0)==True:
        figus=comprar_figus(figus_total)

        for j  in album:
          if album[j]!=figus:
```

Esta ultima función tendría que ver si la figu esta en el álbum y reemplazar, es decir si sale la figu 7 cambiaría en el indice 7 que tengo un cero y pondría un 7 y el resto serian ceros, no se como seguir.

Comment: Hola silvana,no se muy bien  que esperas obtener,  no termino de ver la lógica. Dices "cambiaría en el indice 7 que tengo un cero y pondría un 7 ", vale, ¿si sale 1 cambias el índice 1 por un 1 y así con todos? Entonces tenemos un problema. Primero, el primer índice de una lista es el 0, no el uno, esto hace que tu while sea infinito porque el primer elemento siempre será 0. en realidad no será infinito porque terminarás tarde o temprano con un índice inválido, si figus_total es 8 por ejemplo, 8 no es un índice válido para una lista de 8 elementos (indices de 0 a 7)

Comment: Para generar índices válidos debería ser  debería ser `random.randint(0,figus_total-1)`, pero si corregimos eso , el while si sería infinito como comentaba, si sale un 0 le asignamos 0 al índice 0 por lo que siempre hay al menos un cero en la lista y  jamás terminará el ciclo. Creo que deberías explicar cual es la lógica del programa, porque me parece que estamos ante un [problema XY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Answer (score 1):

tampoco entiendo muy bien que es lo que tiene que hacer la función, pero me surge una duda:
Se supone que la función "hay_Alguno(l,e)" tiene que devolverte True si hay algún e en l? porque tal y como está ahora lo que hace es comprobar solo el primer elemento de la lista y devolver True si es igual o False si no lo es, y ahí termina puesto que encuentra un return.

Si lo que quieres es saber si hay algún elemento que coincida, con una función, puedes hacer algo así:

```
def hay_Alguno(l,e):
    return True if e in l else False
```

Para obtener una lista de los elementos que coinciden, algo así:

```
def hay_Alguno(l,e):
    return list(map(lambda x:x==e,l))
```

Como han dicho antes, con algo más de explicación, podremos entender mejor qué necesitas.